# Calculating non-integer exponents in iOS

Tags: objective-c, c, math, exponent, shunting-yard

I've been working on my math parser a bit, and I have come to realize that a bit of code I'm using is unable to handle an exponent that is non-interger. The bit of code I'm using seems to work just fine with an `int`, but not with a `double`.

```
else if ([[token stringValue] isEqualToString: @"^"])
    {
        NSLog(@"^");
        double exponate = [[self popOperand] intValue];
        double base     = [[self popOperand] doubleValue];
        result = base;
        exponate--;
        while (exponate)
        {
            result *= base;
            exponate--;
        }
        [self.operandStack addObject:  [NSNumber numberWithDouble: result]];

    }
```

'
Using Objective-C, how do I make something like  5^5.5  evaluate properly? (6987.71242969)

Comment: Any reason you are not using `pow()` for exponentiation?

Comment: I had never up until this point needed to use it. I'm pretty much self taught. But thanks, another tool I didn't know about added to the toolbox.

Comment: @JoeMillion Also, FYI, the second operand is called the "exponent", not an "exponate".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let [library code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/pow.3.html) do the work for you:

```
double exponent = [[self popOperand] doubleValue];
double base = [[self popOperand] doubleValue];

[self.operandStack addObject:@(pow(base, exponent))];
```

Comment: Don’t forget to `#include <math.h>`

Answer (score 2):

Josh's answer is right, I just wanted to add something about using floats in conditions:

```
double exponate = [[self popOperand] intValue];
exponate--;
while (exponate)
{
    result *= base;
    exponate--;
}
```

This can lead to an infinite loop because of rounding erros `while (exponate)` might never evaluate to `false`. If you are using `doubles` or `floats` as loop variables, always do something like `while (myFloat > 0.0)`